# Where are the following functions differentiable? Where are they holomorphic? Determine their derivatives at points where they are differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$ f(z) = e^{−x}e^{−iy}$$

I used the Cauchy Riemann equations to determine that $x=iy-\ln(i)$, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to conclude. Could I say that the function is differentiable wherever $x=iy-\ln(i)$?

Comment: How did you get to your result?

Comment: @menag yea...I just realized something....when we determine the $u$ and the $v$ to be used in the C-R equations, we need to remove the $i$ don't we...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
In my opinion you are not working with the right expressions for $u$ and $v.$
It is $$f(z)=e^{-z}=e^{-x}e^{-iy}=e^{-x}\cos y-ie^{-x}\sin y.$$ So $$u(x,y)=e^{-x}\cos y$$ and $$v(x,y)=-e^{-x}\sin y.$$

Now check if $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x.$

Comment: Wait, why couldn't I use $u=-e^{-x}$ and $v=-e^{-y}$?

Comment: No. $u(x,y)$ is the real part of $f(z)$ and $v(x,y)$ is the imaginary part of $f(z).$ That is, you have to write $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ with $u,v$ reals.

Comment: Ok so I see you used euler's equation, but wouldnt that make $u=-e^{-x}cos(y)$?

Comment: It is $e^{-iy}=\cos (-y)+i\sin(-y)=\cos y-i\sin y.$ That is, I have used $\cos(-y)=\cos y.$

Comment: Ah ok. So I figured out that both of the C-R equations match. Is it enough to just say that the given $f(z)$ is holomorphic? The question asks me to specify where this occurs. Is there maybe a better way of saying it other than ''at all values of $z$''?

Comment: Check that they match at every $(x,y).$ Thus you can conclude that the function is holomorphic in the whole plane. Moreover, you should obtain $f'(z)=-e^{-z}=-f(z).$

Comment: Ok I see how you got that last part, but what's the significance of it? Or is that part answering the last part of the question?

Comment: It is the derivative you should get.